# How to fetch an entity without its to-many relationships

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have a model, where I have an entity called "Category". This Category has a one-to-many relationship called "Products". How do I set up the fetch request to only get the Category entities WITHOUT the products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you query against `Category`, product elements are loaded as faults. This is the default behavior of CoreData.

On the contrary if you use `- (void)setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:(NSArray *)keys`, you can load (**pre-fetch**) products when the request is executed.

From [Core Data App](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001202-CJBDBHCB)

> Faulting reduces the amount of memory your application consumes. A
>   fault is a placeholder object that represents a managed object that
>   has not yet been fully realized, or **a collection object that
>   represents a relationship**:
>
> A managed object fault is an instance of the appropriate class, but
>   its persistent variables are not yet initialized. A relationship fault
>   is a subclass of the collection class that represents the
>   relationship. Faulting allows Core Data to put boundaries on the
>   object graph. Because a fault is not realized, a managed object fault
>   consumes less memory, and managed objects related to a fault are not
>   required to be represented in memory at all.

and

> **Pre-fetching** is in effect a special case of
>   batch-faulting, performed immediately after another fetch. The idea
>   behind pre-fetching is the anticipation of future needs. When you
>   fetch some objects, sometimes you know that soon after you will also
>   need related objects which may be represented by faults. To avoid the
>   inefficiency of individual faults firing, **you can pre-fetch the
>   objects at the destination**.

**Edit**

If you need to count the number of products for a specific category, use `- (NSUInteger)countForFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request error:(NSError **)error` using a request like the following:

```
NSFetchRequest* request = // set up a request for Products
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"toCategory == %@", currentCategory]];
// count for fetch request here...
```

where `toCategory` is the inverse relationship from `Products` to `Category` and `currentCategory` is the category you have.

Comment: Okay... Just for clarification, this means that if I inspect the products count in my category it shows me the actual count of related products, but the products don't consume any memory because they're not yet instantiated?! And as soon as I want to access a product, Core Data dynamically retrieves it from the persistent store?

Comment: @ASP Yes but you should take care of faults. If you access a property for any Category, then it will fire a fault (Core Data will make a round trip and will retrieve data for you). I added an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the docs for NSFetchRequest

You can set 'includeSubentities' and 'returnsObjectsAsFaults' to restrict what data comes back from Core Data with your model (Product)

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html